# Get text from dll using index

Tags: c#, string, dll

How can I get strings from windows dlls like mssvp.dll and themeui.dll using the index?
In the registry or theme files there are some strings (like DisplayName in themes) that are pointing to a dll and an index number instead of the real texts. For example I have:
DisplayName=@%SystemRoot%\System32\themeui.dll,-2106 in windows theme file. So how can I retrieve the real strings from those dlls using C# and .Net 4.0?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No; he wants to know how to get a string from the string table of a DLL.  He will need P/Invoke.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, I realized just now..

Comment: Use LoadLibrary() to load the DLL, LoadString() to load the string from the resource table, FreeLibrary() to unload the DLL again.  Flip the sign on the resource number.  Visit the pinvoke.net website to get the pinvoke declarations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use P/Invoke:

```
    /// <summary>Returns a string resource from a DLL.</summary>
    /// <param name="DLLHandle">The handle of the DLL (from LoadLibrary()).</param>
    /// <param name="ResID">The resource ID.</param>
    /// <returns>The name from the DLL.</returns>
    static string GetStringResource(IntPtr handle, uint resourceId) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(8192);     //Buffer for output from LoadString()

        int length = NativeMethods.LoadString(handle, resourceId, buffer, buffer.Capacity);

        return buffer.ToString(0, length);      //Return the part of the buffer that was used.
    }


    static class NativeMethods {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        internal static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint wID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int FreeLibrary(IntPtr hLibModule);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem. My index is a negative number like -2106 so I can't use it with uint. I tried changing that to int or IntPtr but that didn't work. So how can I pass a negative resourceId ?

Comment: @SepehrM: Try an unchecked cast to `uint` or `ushort`.

Comment: If the index number is negative, its absolute value should be used.